How to correlate Intel Pin tool memory access logs with ftrace page fault logs?
I’m working on correlating memory access logs generated by the Pin tool with page fault logs from ftrace. Both logs contain timestamps and addresses, but I’m facing issues when trying to match the memory accesses with the corresponding page faults. Here's a breakdown of the logs and the problem I'm encountering.
Pin Logs (Memory Accesses)
I'm using the pinatrace.cpp tool from pintool/source/tools/ManualExamples/. The command I run is:
../../../pin -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so -- ls
The Pin log outputs look like this for memory accesses:
13746.948842: 0x72f1e9532543: W 0x7ffcebf1a788
ftrace Logs (Page Faults)
I capture page fault events with ftrace, and the logs are in the following format:
ls-39090   [003] d.... 13747.755595: page_fault_user: address=0x7fb30b788000 ip=0x7fb31f3fabf3 error_code=0x6
The Issue
I see mismatches between the logs (e.g., nearly all page faults do not have a matching access address from the pin tool log).
What I tried

Disabling ASLR to ensure addresses are not randomized.
Attempting to match using page numbers instead of full addresses.
Looking for exact timestamp matches between the logs.

Despite these efforts, I haven’t been able to successfully correlate the memory accesses and page faults.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
